# Align <span> at bottom of <ul>

Tags: html, css

I have an image carousel whose HTML is fixed. Trying to align the captions of each image so that it is at the bottom of the `<ul>` but I can't seem to get it to look right.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wwa4jxm/6/)

### Here is my HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="someImage.jpg">
            <span class="caption">Some Caption</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="someImage.jpg">
            <span class="caption">Some Caption</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### My CSS

```
.carousel img {
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.carousel li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
    transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
}
.carousel .caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240,0.75);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Just add to .carousel li, a vertical-align: middle/top/whatever and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your images to be central aligned inside of the their containers. For this I would add a wrapper around the image so that this can sit nicely inside of its `li`

```
 //Markup
<div><img src="https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/ConstantContact/Bematech/images/br200bt.png" /></div>
 //css
 .carousel li img {
     position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

Also since css has got hell'a sexy you can now use transforms to center align vertical and horizontal.

Please see this [Sexy little Fiddle (might not be sexy)](http://jsfiddle.net/1wwa4jxm/10/)

Comment: Yeah, that should actually work. The way my carousel works is it build the HTML elements from a simple `<ul>` and `<li>` markup. Will test tomorrow when I am back in the office.

Comment: change the div to img... As your css has fixed widths and heights it shoudl still be ok. Sorry I missed the html is fixed

Comment: I really only said the HTML was fixed because earlier people were giving me answers with crazy manipulated HTML. Can you just explain what the percentages work off of? works perfectly on the `img` but I know the `left: 50%` and top are 50% of the parent div, but how does the transform work?

Comment: The nifty thing about the translate is it applys the rules to itself. Meaning, you can get it to to the negative on itself. If the image is `100px` wide and tall and you do `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` Thats the same (in this case) as writting `-50px`

Comment: Awesome! Thats great to know for future centering. thanks for the help Jamie!

Answer (score 0):

Please try following css

```
.carousel li {
display: block;
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
-moz-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
-ms-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
-o-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
float:left;
```

}